# Javascript - Check Amazon Objects to see if defined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I get an error if part of the Amazon product is missing. For example, I can do this check:

```
typeof success.data[i].OfferSummary[0].LowestNewPrice[0].Amount !== "undefined"
```

but if OfferSummary is not defined this would throw an error. Do I need to check every object under the data? Is there an easier way?

I was thinking of doing a try ... catch and trapping the error, but I'm sure someone has run into this before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you'll need to check at each step or wrap the check in a try catch block.

At the moment you're trying to access a property on undefined, which does not exist.

```
if (success.data[i] && success.data[i].OfferSummary[0] && 
    success.data[i].OfferSummary[0].LowestNewPrice[0] && 
    success.data[i].OfferSummary[0].LowestNewPrice[0].Amount !== undefined) {}

//OR

var amount = null;
try {
  amount = success.data[i].OfferSummary[0].LowestNewPrice[0].Amount;
} catch( err ) {}
if (amount !== undefined){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `lodash` you may use function [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs#get):

```
var amount = _.get(success, 'data[' + i + '].OfferSummary[0].LowestNewPrice[0].Amount', 0);
```

The 3rd parameter is default value which will be returned in case of smth in this path is not defined.

Actually, under the hood it's just a set of `if`-checks but the code looks more elegant.